# If statement then click event in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to only allow a click event to fire if a function return is true. I am not sure if this is the correct syntax or not. Any help would be awesome.

```
onclick="if(AveryValidateAddress())Shipping.save()"
```

Comment: *"I am not sure if this is the correct syntax or not."*? Have you tried it? Did it work? Are you asking if there is a better way?

Comment: Yes, your syntax is correct, although not a best practice. Instead of putting code into your inline `onclick` handler, write a separate save function and add it via `addEventListener`.

Comment: FYI, `addEventListener` is not supported by some/all versions of Internet Explorer.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon - I have tried it and no it did not work. I get an error telling me that AveryValidateAddress is undefined, though that is the exact name of the function it references.

Comment: @KevinSchultz Your function must be in a closure. Check if you function is not inside a DOM ready or any other function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would you not include the check Inside the function ?

HTML

```
onclick="myFunction()"
```

JS

```
myFunction = function(){
  if (!AveryValidateAddress()){
     //Dont do anything if it's false
     return
  }
  else{
      Shipping.save()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
onclick="AveryValidateAddress() && Shipping.save()"
```

Answer (score -1):

The way you have it written, you could accomplish this by taking advantage of the `&&` operator's lazy evaluation. If the first part of your `and` statement evaluates to `false`, it won't attempt to evaluate the second part.

```
onclick="AveryValidateAddress() && Shipping.save()"
```

However, since you're using jQuery, a better approach would be to take advantage of jQuery's event binding:

```
<a href="#" id="saveButton">Click to save</a>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#saveButton').click(function(){
       if( AveryValidateAddress() ){
          Shipping.save();
       }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Where does it say he is using jQuery?

Comment: @SableFoste He had the jQuery tag on the question before it was edited